# How to get the table name and column name from data model of selected cell in excel API

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Currently I am working on Excel add in which is present in office developer tools.

But I am very much new to this. I have a requirement which is described in below lines.

Is there a way to get table name and column name from where the data is fetched(i.e if a cube formula contains a cell name as C1 then is there any possibility to get table name and column name corresponding to value in C1 in data model) based on the cell names that are present in cube formula. Currently I am getting all the Cell values corresponding to Cell names in cube formula.

But I didnt find a way to get the table specific details.

Could you please help me in achieving the above scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the watch window to examine the `Range("c1")` object

```
columnNumber = Range("c1").Column

tableName = Range("c1").ListObject.Name
```